# Permutations with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

I have a problem that can be modeled as:

there are 8 boxes in total, and 60 different items. I want to put all items into boxes (all of them can be put into a single box).

Now I want to find:

1) the number of total posssible situations

2) the number of posssible situations when certain number of items are put into certain box (such are 6 different items are put into box #2).

**Edit:**

I found a somehow similar problem, but I think my data would be too large to enumerate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721161/combinations-between-two-lists

Comment: Is this a *Mathematica* related question, or did you mean to post this on *MATH.stackexchange.com*?

Comment: I want to use mathematica to solve this problem, but I have no clue about where to start with.

Comment: I think if you only want to know the number (instead of figuring out explicit elements), it's indeed a math problem.

Comment: 6 in box 2: `60!/54! 54^7`..  mathematica will crunch the numbers but you need to work out the math on your own. (this problem is far to large for direct simulation)

Comment: bzzt, guilty of commenting before coffee again. I'll post an answer with the correct result

Comment: Are the boxes distinguishable? I am guessing yes since question 2 has the concept of "a certain box", distinguished by a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it useful to work through the sort of problem with a smaller example:

```
 nbox = 4;
 nball = 5;
```

generate all ball-to-box binnings:

```
 boxassign = Tuples[Range[nbox], {nball}];
 boxassign[[;; 10]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

the formula for the total count is pretty obvious i think:

```
 (boxassign // Length ) == nbox^nball
```

> True

Now transpose that to a list of the balls in each box:
(I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this, but this is clearly readable)

```
 ballinbox = 
     Function[box, Sort@Flatten@Position[#, box]] /@ Range[nbox] & /@ boxassign;
 ballinbox[[1 ;; 10]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Now select the cases where there are three balls in box two for example:

```
  nintwo = 3;
 ( byintwo = Select[ ballinbox , Length[#[[2]]] == nintwo & ] ) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

you can inspect the unique sets in box two and observe that it is all the possible subsets:

```
 Union@(byintwo[[ ;; , 2]])
 Length[%]   ==  nball! / nintwo! / (nball - nintwo)!
```

> True

Now the total count is just that number multiplied be all the ways we can distribute the remaining balls:

```
Length[byintwo] == 
     ( nball! / nintwo! / (nball - nintwo)! ) (nbox - 1)^(nball - nintwo)
```

> True

so that for the example:

```
 Clear[nball,nintwo,nbox]; (* oops!! *)
 ( nball! / nintwo! / (nball - nintwo)! ) (nbox - 1)^(nball - nintwo) /.
      {nball -> 60, nintwo -> 6, nbox -> 8}
```

> 216181483166095764640743948702606019893283529061497140

Comment: Unfortunately: $\frac{60!}{6!54!} 7^{54}=216181483166095764640743948702606019893283529061497140\neq 262440$

Comment: DOH!  @ubpdqn  i will fix that, good catch

Answer (score 0):

@capsensitive;

Hi;

1)

I am viewing this as a labeled balls into labeled urns because all 60 in the last urn is different then all 60 in the first urn.

I have a little function for computing these:

```
m[distballs_,disturns_,occupiedurns_]:=
Binomial[disturns,occupiedurns]Sum[(-1)^j  
Binomial[occupiedurns,j](occupiedurns-j)^distballs,  
{j,0,occupiedurns}]
```

where distballs = 60, disturns = 8, occupied urns = 1 to 8 because there can be 0 urns empty or 7 urns empty.

```
Sum[m[60,8,k],{k,1,8}]
```

yields:

1532495540865888858358347027150309183618739122183602176

A fair amount of assumptions were made but that is how I would do it. I do agree that the question belongs on Mathematics.SE.

Comment: For the first item you have 8 possibilities, for the second item you have 8 possibilities, for the third item you have 8 possibilities... err... etc. `8^60`